# Voice video and text chat, screen sharing, conference all in one tool?

Tags: video-conferencing, skype, screen-sharing

I am looking for a software that could fulfill all the following needs :

- Conference calling with up to 10-15 people
- Video, Text, Voice chat
- Groups/Servers/Friend list
- Screen sharing
- All of the above for : Desktop app, Phone app (optional), and web app
- As secured as possible

Optionally :
 - Professional/Ergonomic looking interface
 - Lightweight/Optimised

Up until now, I was using Skype and Webex to fulfill all these needs. But these two don't even do these task that well, and have some poor performances.

The solution I have found that is as close as possible to this is Discord. Which seems to do everything better than these two. Except for one crucial use of Webex, which is the screen sharing with people login in from the web app (I tried making it work on discord, but to no avail).

Is there a way to make wep app screen sharing work on discord ? If not, is there another alternative that could fulfill that need ? Maybe a streaming software could do the trick ?

Comment: Have you tried Google Meet?